# Wordpress: insert list of coma seperated words using wp_insert_term as individual terma

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Wordpress Question:
insert list of coma seperated words using wp_insert_term as individual terms

Hi all ,
i am working on developing custom type post , which pulls data from wp_videos database.
example:  imdb movie details

Problem : list of actors to be inserted into custom taxanomy field, the code is working but the problem is i am unable to post individual words as seperate terms  .

WP_database --> Column Name Stars contains
Robert Downey Jr., Gwyneth Paltrow, Terrence

CODE :

```
wp_insert_term(
''.$video['stars'].'',          // the term 
'movie-actor',                 // the taxonomy
 array(
'description'=> ''.$video['stars'].'',
'slug' => ''.$video['stars'].'',                   

    )
 );
```

Robert Downey Jr., Gwyneth Paltrow, Terrence is added as single term

please help.. how do i **loop the above code** for all stars to insert as individual terms.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to split the string by a comma, and then loop through the result array to perform the given operation for each movie star:

```
$starArray = explode(',', $stars);
$starArray = array_map('trim', $starArray); // remove spaces

foreach ($starArray as $star) {
    // do the insert
}
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/hZg6ARai)